# How to eliminate double value change in datepicker (material)?

Tags: angular

There is a problem with the datepicker (Material Design) component with valueChanges. When we use min / max inputs, a double change occurs. Thus, for example, we receive two requests to the server instead of one.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duww9x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinctUntilChanged` :

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plyb7a?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(
    (p, n) => p.fromDate === n.fromDate && p.toDate === n.toDate
  )
).subscribe(value => {
  this.count += 1;
  console.log(value);
});
```